# library for custom android editText with individual boxes for each letter (e.g. otp/pin view) with variable spacing to accommodate multiple words

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've found several libraries for pin/otp views, that is custom edit text views designed to enter pin codes:

□□□□

What I'm looking for is something like this that has variable spacing between letters, to accommodate multiple words:

□□□ □□□

I'm not sure exactly what even to search for, but I can see that there are libraries that do almost what I want, but not quite, for example:

An example being the library here:

https://github.com/ChaosLeong/PinView

I think it would be difficult to implement something like this from scratch, is there anything out there that does what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any library that does such thing. You have 2 options:

1. Insert a PinView for each word, with a margin between each others
2. Modify the PinView library or this library: [PinEditTextField](https://github.com/poovamraj/PinEditTextField)